# Speed issues with laravel 4

Tags: performance, laravel

Im using laravel 4 to develop my site but im getting increaingly concerned with speed issues.

Im developing on a local machine :windows 7, apache and php 5.4

One of my pages creates an article.  The view relies on a simple eloquent query to create a select field.

Using profiler the query is timed at 20ms but the page takes over 4500ms to complete.  Other pages that rely on a record query,  eg edit article take  over 7000ms.

The pages also pull details from the authorised user

In other threads I've followed suggestions to use 127.0.0.1 as the database ip but this hasn't made a difference.

My pages uses jquery,  but nothing heavy just small features.

I use the blade templating

Are my times realistic?

How can i profile to see where the bottlenecks are? Ive tried adding timers using the profiler but not had much success getting them to view.

Are there any standards i should apply?

Does blade add a big overhead? 
I've not posted the code as it would take up all of the room

Comment: Have you profiled anything other than the query? You say "the page takes over 4500ms" but is that "time from request to completion of scripts," or "download time" or something else?  It sounds as though your code is massively inefficient, since I'd expect a page based on a simple query to return in well under 1s, but without profiling or seeing code there's no way to narrow it down.

Comment: It's not likely Laravel or Eloquent itself, but something else. Just do a "brute force" timing using http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php between calls in your page to see where the bottleneck is. That'd be the first step, imo...

Comment: What profiler are you using? Any other packages you have with it or just the default install?